# SharePoint Files Synced to OneDrive twice on computer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, error, file, onedrive-for-business, duplicate

I was moving files from one site to another and an error displayed regarding the file name length. It said something about OK to shorten name and the next thing I know it's rearranged everything in File Explorer. Now anything I do in my synced SharePoint folders or in my computer Documents folder displays twice on my computer.

Should look like this:

[image]

My computer looks like this with all of the folders under "Desktop"

[image]

To troubleshoot

- Rebooted multiple times after all changes
- Disconnected and reconnected OneDrive
- Reviewed and compared the registry for Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders and verified like another users.
- I've reset OneDrive: C:\Program Files\Microsoft OneDrive\onedrive.exe /reset